Force clang not to unroll a loop
I have a loop of the form
for (int i = 0; i < SOME_CONSTANT; ++i) {
    // do some stuff involving `i`.
}

which clang is partially unrolling to do two passes at a time. I need it to not be unrolled at all.
One option is to add an inline assembly barrier to prevent clang/LLVM from seeing how i is modified:
for (int i = 0; i < SOME_CONSTANT; ++i) {
    asm volatile("" : "=r"(i) : "0"(i));
    // do some stuff involving `i`.
}

but I'm wondering if there is a clearer way without resorting to such hacks.

Why do you need to prevent unrolling?

Can you use #pragma clang optimize off?

@Barmar why I need to prevent unrolling is of limited relevance to the question -- someone else might find it years from now and have to prevent unrolling for a different reason, which is why I phrased it in as general of terms as possible. But to answer your question, I need to prevent unrolling in this case because I am writing eBPF code and the unrolled loop ends up making the code too complex for the eBPF verifier to verify.

These are often XY problems so understanding why can lead to better solutions to the main problem.

Re "why I need to prevent unrolling is of limited relevance to the question", No, because questions that ask for a setting (since you ruled out hacks) -- questions that would easily be answered by looking at the manual --  are bad questions. If you give a reason, then there's a chance the X of the XY problem could be addressed.

Okay, well, I have now explained in my comment why I want to do this. Do you agree that it’s a reasonable reason to want to prevent the loop from being unrolled?

Just use #pragma unroll(1) before the loop (note #pragma GCC unroll 1 also works well since Clang also supports it)

@larsks No, disabling optimization is a really bad idea performance wise. It causes variables to be  massively stored and reload from memory, even loop iterators...

This question is similar to: Loop unrolling in clang. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

clang is quite aggressive with vectorization, even at "-O2" - and you may need to minimize that as well, so I'll add them here. The following pragma only affects the next loop statement:
_Pragma("clang loop unroll(disable) vectorize(disable)")
for (int i = 0; i < SOME_CONSTANT; ++i) {
    // do some stuff involving `i`.
}

I've needed this for my own purposes, and spent some time chasing up version numbers that support these options. This requires: __clang_major__.__clang_minor__ >= 3.7, which is ancient, and corresponds to Apple's hacked Xcode release version: __apple_build_version__ >= (7000072))
FYI, (__GNUC__ >= 8), provides the loop pragma: _Pragma("GCC unroll (0)");  and (__GNUC__ >= 14) finally provides: _Pragma("GCC novector") - earlier versions need to use optimization options, or various inline asm tricks.
